# Groovy character encoding result mismatch for unsupported character

Tags: java, php, groovy, utf-8, character-encoding

This is so far my analysis and obstacle, suppose for the character below, which is basically supported by “UTF-8” character set and has not supported to “EUC-JP”.
“―”
For php, there is a method “var_dump(input_string)” to convert any string into byte array with encoding “EUC-JP”, in this case, it returns,

```
[161, 189, 10] //Note: [3]=>int(10) for Line Feed.
```

similarly, when I produce the byte array with encoding “UTF-8”, in this case it returns,

```
[226, 128, 141,10] //Note: [4]=>int(10) for Line Feed.
```

But, when I tried the same thing in Groovy,
It behaves totally differently, For EUC-JP the byte arrangement as follows,

```
[-95, -67, 10] //Note: [3]=>int(10) for Line Feed.
```

For UTF-8,

```
[-30, -128, -107, 10] //Note: [4]=>int(10) for Line Feed.
```

N.B., I fetched the data directly from 2 different text file encoded with EUC-JP and UTF-8 respectively. The last byte of all the above arrays are for LF (Line Feed). As the byte arrangement is different for same character encoding for those two language, it’s not possible to match produced hash in between.

Here is code sample so far, Start with php,

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("euc_jp.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$str1 = fread($myfile,filesize("euc_jp.txt"));

echo "Read From File EUC-JP:<br/>";
echo $str1;
$byte_array1 = unpack('C*', $str1);
echo "<br/>Byte Dump of EUC-JP File Content:<br/>";
var_dump($byte_array1);

echo "<br/><br/>";
$myfile2 = fopen("utf_8.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$str2 = fread($myfile2,filesize("utf_8.txt"));

echo "<br/><br/>";
echo "Read From File UTF-8:<br/>";
echo $str2;
$byte_array2 = unpack('C*', $str2);
echo "<br/>Byte Dump of EUC-JP File Content:<br/>";
var_dump($byte_array2);


$encodedToEucJp = mb_convert_encoding($str2, "EUC_JP");
echo "<br/><br/>After conversion (UTF-8) to (EUC-JP): <br/>";
echo $encodedToEucJp;

echo "<br/><br/>";

echo "Hash Generation Directly From EUC-JP:<br/>";
print_r(md5($str1));

echo "<br/><br/>";
echo "Hash Generation From UTF-8 File Content After Encoded to EUC-JP:<br/>";
print_r(md5($encodedToEucJp));

fclose($myfile);
fclose($myfile2);
?>
```

For Groovy,

```
println(new File('/var/www/html/euc_jp.txt').getText('EUC-JP').getBytes("EUC-JP"))
println(new File('/var/www/html/utf_8.txt').getText('UTF-8').getBytes("UTF-8"))
```

This is so far my obstacle, first of all the byte representation for those two language is different, if it’s not a limitation of Groovy as well as Java8, how do I produce the same byte arrangement that produced by php, secondly, what is the equivalent code for the native php function, b_convert_encoding(). So, that I able to convert any string encoding, where there might have some character that doesn’t support by both the encoding mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java and Groovy bytes are [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) **signed** values, i.e. the value of one byte is between `-128` and `+127`.

To calculate the corresponding unsigned value for the same one byte, add `256` to a negative value, e.g. `-95 + 256 = 161`

So, what you see are the **same bytes**. It's just that PHP prints the values as *unsigned*, and Groovy prints the values as *signed*. They are still the same 8 bits in a byte.

```
Unsigned             Signed                 Hex
161, 189, 10      == -95, -67, 10        == A1, BD, 0A
226, 128, 141, 10 == -30, -128, -115, 10 == E2, 80, 8D, 0A
226, 128, 149, 10 == -30, -128, -107, 10 == E2, 80, 95, 0A
```

`E2 80 8D` is UTF-8 for [Unicode Character 'ZERO WIDTH JOINER' (U+200D)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200d/index.htm).

`E2 80 95` is UTF-8 for [Unicode Character 'HORIZONTAL BAR' (U+2015)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2015/index.htm).

If you want to print the values of a byte array as readable text, I suggest you print the bytes using 2-digit HEX. That way every byte is consistently 2 hex-digits long.

Comment: Thank you, your response really help me a lot. I’ve another context in this regard, basically I’m trying to encode a string that includes a character “―”, using php it encodes smoothly to EUC-JP and returns   [161, 189] in byte, but, when I try to encode the same character and same encoding in java it returns simply, ‘?’ in byte it’s [63], where my expectation was [161, 189]. So, what I need to do to solve this problem.

Comment: @Md.HasanBasriAngel That is because “―” (['HORIZONTAL BAR' (U+2015)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2015/index.htm)) doesn't exist in [EUC-JP](http://www.rikai.com/library/kanjitables/kanji_codes.euc.shtml). “—” (['EM DASH' (U+2014)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2014/index.htm)) does, as bytes `A1 BD`.

Comment: @Md.HasanBasriAngel Check again. Unicode character U+2015 is **not** in that list, and that's the character you posted in the comment above *(copy/paste it [here](http://www.endmemo.com/unicode/unicodeconverter.php) if you don't believe me)*. Unicode character U+2014 *is* in the EUC-JP character list, but that's a **different** character, even though they look very much alike. Read my [previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49548958/groovy-character-encoding-result-mismatch-for-unsupported-character/49549067?noredirect=1#comment86128732_49549067) again!!

Comment: Thank you once again, Sorry for the earlier message, please ignore that. but my question is, in **php** they manage it somehow through this conversion function, **mb_convert_encoding($str2, "EUC_JP")**. I'm basically looking for the similar mechanism in groovy as well as in java.

Comment: @Md.HasanBasriAngel Java follows the **specification**. PHP spits on specifications and [does whatever it feels like](https://eev.ee/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/). Don't expect other languages to do that. If you want all characters that "looks similar" to map to the same EUC_JP character, then you need to find a definition of "looks similar", if such a definition even exists.

Comment: Thank you so much.